# Roslyn analyzers not working during build for some projects

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

We are currently using some roslyn analyzers, e.g. the `StyleCop.Analyzers` package.

I've created a `.ruleset` file for one of our projects.
In other projects I'm referencing the `.ruleset` file of this project.

In most projects roslyn analyzed the code and generated some build warnings, but we have some projects, which don't get analyzed by it during build.

When I open the files manually in Visual Studio, it will display them as warnings as it should have done during build already.

The settings in the affected projects in Code Analysis are:

- [ ] Enable Code Analysis on Build
- [X] Suppress results from generated code (managed only)
- Rules for `Acme.Web` (under "Run this rule set:")

The roslyn nuget package is only referenced in the project with the `.ruleset` file.

Adding it to the other projects didn't help so far.

How can I change this, so that the project will also get analyzed during build?

Comment: Do the analyzers show up in the project references? Have you tried enabling "Enable Code Analysis on Build"?

Comment: We installed the ```StyleCop.Analyzers``` for all projects in the solution. Unfortunately setting the ```Enable Code Analysis on Build``` option didn't cause it to run the ```StyleCop.Analyzers``` rules to be enforced.

Comment: Do your .csproj have the `CodeAnalysisRuleSet` set to the ruleset file? Have you added the analyzer NuGet packages to the projects?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Yes we added the NuGet package to all projects. Also the ```CodeAnalysisRuleSet``` is referenced in the projects.

Comment: We have the same problem. "Enable Code Analysis on Build" activated, ruleset defined, but errors are only shown while the files are opened in the editor...
@StefanSchmid: Did you find any solution?